# File specific TypeScript annotation for environment, like browser or node

Tags: node.js, typescript, browser, universal

I'm trying to write a universal React.js application using TypeScript and if possible it would like to somehow annotate certain TypeScript files in such a way that a file is understood to be running inside a browser context or Node.js context explicitly. So that any attempt to use browser APIs from within Node.js environment would fail, and vice versa. How can I do that?

Right now the files reside in the same directory and maybe that the problem because I cannot have multiple tsconfig files but if that is the only solution I guess I have to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Each project described by a `tsconfig.json` file has a single set of visible declarations; there's no way to have different declarations visible in different files in the same project.  You can put a `<reference>` directive in a specific file, but the directive will affect the entire project.  So to enforce what you want using the regular type checker, you'll need to use multiple `tsconfig.json` files.  There may be other approaches such as using the tslint "ban" rule to ban all APIs from one environment in a specific file, but I doubt they will be practical.